# Terraform code to create cloud watch event that triggers a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I am new to IaC and am looking to send an email to owners of aws resources where they don't apply correct tagging. We have managed tag rule set up in aws config and I am looking to use cloudwatch events to trigger when something is considered non-compliant which will then in turn target a lambda function that will utilize SES to send an email to the owner of the invalid resource requesting them to fix.

As mentioned, I am just dipping my toes in at this stage and looking to see if somebody has a use case where they achieved a similar result.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Do you have a specific question? If you're just looking for experience or opinions, I'd recommend asking at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: What's your level of experience?  Have you worked with terraform before, say using it to deploy a VM?

Comment: Pretty much zero experience however I will be adding to a code base that is already doing a bunch of aws creation. Aws config rules are in place already. I just want to create a terraform module to create a cloudwatch event that targets a lambda function (which I will create as well).